# Dynamically add input boxes to an edit form in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5) on how to build a component for joomla 2.5, but now I am stuck.

What I want to do:
Besided thoses field defined in admin\models\forms\.xml I want to **dynamically** add form fields. The field list should be read from database.

I have a:

- main table `#__tours(id, title)`,
- field list table `#__tourfields(id,lable,description,position)`
- field value table `#__tourfieldvalues(tourid,fieldid,fieldvalue)`

`#__tourfields` contains a list of additional fields, that the user may want to specify for each entry in `#__tours`. `#__tourfieldvalues` would contain the values for the additional fields.

So now I need to figure out how to add input boxes to the edit form for each row in `#__tourfields`, read the values in `#__tourfieldvalues` for the currently to display entry of `#__tours`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you experimented with calling from the database and using a `foreach` statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is very complex question. Subject to small book :)

In general you have to create class for every field type and initiate this class for every field in `#__tourfields`. This class have to extend `JFormField` and have `getInput()` method overridden.

Then in cycle you fetch your fields.

Something like this. But I believe you have to have more specific question. This one sounds like "How to create CMS like Joomla from scratch?"